# By conditional group, how to sum object with others that has the same key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have a one dimensional array objects and I need the sum of values of a specific group inside his parent object.

basicaly I have this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "group level 1 - Jhon",
        "code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "group level 2 - James",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "group level 3 - Jack",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "1.1",
        "stacked_code": "1.1.1",
        "expectation_2025": 0,
        "expectation_2024": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "group level 2 - Jony",
        "code": "2",
        "parent_code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1.2"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "group level 3 - Any",
        "code": "2",
        "parent_code": "1.2",
        "stacked_code": "1.2.2",
        "expectation_2027": 4,
        "expectation_2026": 15,
        "expectation_2025": 2.50,
        "expectation_2024": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "group level 3 - Bob",
        "code": "3",
        "parent_code": "1.2",
        "stacked_code": "1.2.3",
        "expectation_2027": 7,
        "expectation_2025": 3.50,
        "expectation_2024": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "group level 1 - Joel",
        "code": "2",
        "stacked_code": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "group level 1 - Julie",
        "code": "3",
        "stacked_code": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": 40,
        "name": "group level 2 - Julie",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "3",
        "stacked_code": "3.1"
    }
]
```

I expect something like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "group level 1 - Jhon",
        "code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1",
        "expectation_2027": 11,
        "expectation_2026": 15,
        "expectation_2025": 6,
        "expectation_2024": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "group level 2 - James",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1.1",
        "expectation_2027": 0,
        "expectation_2026": 0,
        "expectation_2025": 0,
        "expectation_2024": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "group level 3 - Jack",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "1.1",
        "stacked_code": "1.1.1",
        "expectation_2025": 0,
        "expectation_2024": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "group level 2 - Jony",
        "code": "2",
        "parent_code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1.2",
        "expectation_2027": 11,
        "expectation_2026": 15,
        "expectation_2025": 6,
        "expectation_2024": 7
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "group level 3 - Any",
        "code": "2",
        "parent_code": "1.2",
        "stacked_code": "1.2.2",
        "expectation_2027": 4,
        "expectation_2026": 15,
        "expectation_2025": 2.50,
        "expectation_2024": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "group level 3 - Bob",
        "code": "3",
        "parent_code": "1.2",
        "stacked_code": "1.2.3",
        "expectation_2027": 7,
        "expectation_2025": 3.50,
        "expectation_2024": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "group level 1 - Joel",
        "code": "2",
        "stacked_code": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "group level 1 - Julie",
        "code": "3",
        "stacked_code": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": 40,
        "name": "group level 2 - Julie",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "3",
        "stacked_code": "3.1"
    }
]
```

I need to sum the keys that starts with "expectation_" and the same year that their brothers with same level, then put the sum into their parents.

To illustrate the example: (*I have "expectation_" keys only in level 3). So, I need to sum objects "group level 3 - Any" and "group level 3 - Bob", because they are brothers and belongs to the "parent_code: 1.2" and put the result with the same key into the "stacked_code: 1.2 - group level 2 - Jony", and respectively the same whith his "parent_code: 1 group level 1 - Jhon".

I tried:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": 29,
        "name": "group level 1 - Jhon",
        "code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "group level 2 - James",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "group level 3 - Jack",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "1.1",
        "stacked_code": "1.1.1",
        "expectation_2025": 0,
        "expectation_2024": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "group level 2 - Jony",
        "code": "2",
        "parent_code": "1",
        "stacked_code": "1.2"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "group level 3 - Any",
        "code": "2",
        "parent_code": "1.2",
        "stacked_code": "1.2.2",
        "expectation_2027": 4,
        "expectation_2026": 15,
        "expectation_2025": 2.50,
        "expectation_2024": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "group level 3 - Bob",
        "code": "3",
        "parent_code": "1.2",
        "stacked_code": "1.2.3",
        "expectation_2027": 7,
        "expectation_2025": 3.50,
        "expectation_2024": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "group level 1 - Joel",
        "code": "2",
        "stacked_code": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "group level 1 - Julie",
        "code": "3",
        "stacked_code": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": 40,
        "name": "group level 2 - Julie",
        "code": "1",
        "parent_code": "3",
        "stacked_code": "3.1"
    }
];

const parents = arr.filter((value, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) => (
        t.parent_code === value.parent_code && t.parent_code !== undefined
    ))
);
//console.log('parents: ', parents);
parents.map(parent => {
    //console.log('parents: ', parents);
  const groupToSum = arr.filter(f => (parent.parent_code === f.parent_code));

  groupToSum.map(itemToSum => {

    if (itemToSum.parent_code.includes('.')) { // First sum level 2, after level 1
      //console.log('itemToSum: ', itemToSum);

      const keysYears = Object.keys(itemToSum).filter(key => key.startsWith("expectation_"));
      const lineYear = keysYears.map((year, i) => {
        // console.log('year: ', year, i);
        return {
          code: itemToSum.parent_code,
          [year]: groupToSum.reduce((total, obj) => obj[year] + total,0)

        };
      });
      // Code 1.2 duplicate...
            console.log(lineYear.reduce(((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c)), {})); // After, try merge this to the original "arr", with your respective code...
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: The try: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanrn/kr69qLtj/18/